# Calling Controller Action in Area from JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a web application using ASP.NET MVC5. The application has a global script used throughout the site for retrieving user data.

on a click, an ajax call goes back to a url, for examples sake `Area1/Controller/Action` and it receives the user data back. This works fine while working in the root of the site. Once you start working in an Area it returns 404.

If I start viewing `Area1` the request URL becomes `Area1/Controller/Area1/Controller/Action`
I don't really want to put a full `http://` url in the javascript for the ajax call. What other options are there to be sure the correct URL is hit?

Comment: How are you instantiating your script? If you instantiate it with a constructor function you can pass in the url to you action as a parameter, and generate it using @Url.Action(...).

Comment: I have a userprofile object referenced in layout. There is an event hookup on page load that adds a click event to a user class. When clicked it runs the get profile function. I suppose the function could get current url into a variable at start of function, then split it and append the needed url on to address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding the domain to my helpers class which is global throughout my application. Then I can call it when needed.

```
var Helpers = {
    Domain:'http://' + location.hostname + ':' + location.port
};
```

Now when I do an ajax call across areas, I can call `Domain`

```
var options = {
    type: 'POST',
    url: Helpers.Domain + '/Area1/Controller/Action',
    data: JSON.stringify({'username': user }),
    success: function (events) {
        ...
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ...
    }
};

$.ajax(options);
```

Comment: Is there any other answer three years later :) ?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try:

```
url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { area = "Area1"    } )',
```